400 XML specified is not syntactically valid
I am using azure-sdk-for-cpp and I am getting 400 XML specified is not syntactically valid when using CommitBlockList. Is there a way I could see what is wrong with XML?
I've tried to read logs, there is no request body, and I have no idea what is wrong.
void TestClass::Flush()
{  
    UploadBlock();
    for (auto& task : tasks) {
        if (task.valid()) {
            task.get();
        }
    }

    tasks.clear();

    std::copy(uncomitted_blocks_ids.begin(), uncomitted_blocks_ids.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(committed_blocks_ids));


    blob_client.AsBlockBlobClient().CommitBlockList(committed_blocks_ids);

    uncomitted_blocks_ids.clear();
}

void TestClass::Close()
{     
    Flush();

    committed_blocks_ids.clear();
    uncomitted_blocks_ids.clear();
}
void TestClass::UploadBlock()
{
    auto it= m_tasks.begin();
    try {
        for(; it != m_tasks.end(); /*++it*/) {
            if(it->wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready || 
                    m_tasks.size() >= m_network_connections_max){
                it->get();
                it= m_tasks.erase(it);
            }
            else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(::Azure::Storage::StorageException&) {
        tasks.erase(it);
        throw;
    }
    auto block_id = GetBlockId(std::to_string(block_count++));

    m_tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [this, block_data= m_buffer, block_id]() {
        auto block_content = ::Azure::Core::IO::MemoryBodyStream(block_data.data(), block_data.size());

        uncomitted_blocks_ids.push_back(block_id);

        blob_client.AsBlockBlobClient().StageBlock(block_id, block_content);
    }));
}


Can you add your full code which can be very useful?


400 XML specified is not syntactically valid when using CommitBlockList

The 400 XML specified is not syntactically valid error when using CommitBlockList generally indicates that the XML payload generated for committing blocks is invalid or malformed.
You can refer these two Microsoft documents DOC-1 and DOC-2 for uploading proper upload block blobs in the Azure Blob storage.
Here I used the sample code which will upload the file and correct block Id.
Code:
#include <azure/storage/blobs.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <openssl/evp.h>  // OpenSSL for Base64 encoding

using namespace Azure::Storage::Blobs;

const int BlockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;  // 4 MB blocks
const int MaxConcurrency = 8;

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(BlockBlobClient blobClient)
        : blob_client(blobClient), block_count(0) {}

    void UploadBlock();
    void Flush();
    void Close();

private:
    std::string Base64Encode(const std::string& input);
    std::string GetBlockId(const std::string& blockNumber);

    BlockBlobClient blob_client;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> m_tasks; // Store async tasks
    std::vector<std::string> uncomitted_blocks_ids;  // Store uncommitted block IDs
    std::vector<std::string> committed_blocks_ids;   // Store committed block IDs
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_buffer;  // Buffer to hold file data
    int block_count;
    size_t m_network_connections_max = MaxConcurrency;  // Max parallel uploads
};

std::string TestClass::Base64Encode(const std::string& input) {
    size_t encoded_size = 4 * ((input.size() + 2) / 3);
    std::string encoded_string(encoded_size, '\0');
    int len = EVP_EncodeBlock(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&encoded_string[0]),
        reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input.c_str()),
        input.size());
    encoded_string.resize(len);  // Adjust to the actual length
    return encoded_string;
}

std::string TestClass::GetBlockId(const std::string& blockNumber) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << blockNumber;
    return Base64Encode(ss.str());  // Return Base64-encoded block ID
}

void TestClass::UploadBlock() {
    // Read file content into m_buffer
    std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Downloads\\sample5.pdf", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file.");
    }

    std::streamsize file_size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    m_buffer.resize(file_size);
    if (!file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_buffer.data()), file_size)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read file." << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read file.");
    }

    // Split the buffer into blocks and upload
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < file_size) {
        int current_block_size = std::min(BlockSize, static_cast<int>(file_size) - offset);
        std::vector<uint8_t> block_data(m_buffer.begin() + offset, m_buffer.begin() + offset + current_block_size);
        auto block_id = GetBlockId(std::to_string(block_count++));
        uncomitted_blocks_ids.push_back(block_id);
        m_tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [this, block_data = block_data, block_id]() {
            auto block_content = Azure::Core::IO::MemoryBodyStream(block_data.data(), block_data.size());
            blob_client.StageBlock(block_id, block_content);
            }));

        offset += current_block_size;
    }
}

void TestClass::Flush() {
    // Wait for all tasks to complete
    for (auto& task : m_tasks) {
        if (task.valid()) {
            task.get();
        }
    }

    // Clear tasks after completion
    m_tasks.clear();

    // Commit the block list
    blob_client.CommitBlockList(uncomitted_blocks_ids);

    // Add uncommitted blocks to committed list
    std::copy(uncomitted_blocks_ids.begin(), uncomitted_blocks_ids.end(),
        std::back_inserter(committed_blocks_ids));

    // Clear the uncommitted blocks list
    uncomitted_blocks_ids.clear();
    std::cout << "Upload completed successfully." << std::endl;
}

void TestClass::Close() {
    Flush();
    committed_blocks_ids.clear();
    uncomitted_blocks_ids.clear();
}

int main() {
    // Define your connection string, container/blob name, and file path.
    std::string connection_string = "xxxxx";
    std::string container_name = "data";
    std::string blob_name = "test.pdf";

    // Create a BlockBlobClient using the connection string.
    BlobContainerClient container_client = BlobContainerClient::CreateFromConnectionString(connection_string, container_name);
    BlockBlobClient block_blob_client = container_client.GetBlockBlobClient(blob_name);

    // Create an instance of TestClass
    TestClass test_class(block_blob_client);

    // Perform the upload with parallelism.
    test_class.UploadBlock();
    test_class.Flush();

    return 0;
}

Output:
Upload completed successfully.


Portal:


Thanks Venkatesan! My code is working currently, but at high speeds and loads sometimes it crash. That is why we would like to check what is wrong, what is malformed, is there a way to check what is wrong with XML?

Please check the link which I shared it contains how block id should be in format and also error causes.

Is the issue is resolved?

Sorry for delay. Yes it is resolved. The problem was that I have put vector insert operation inside async lambda. After I removed it from the lambda as you suggested in example everything works! Just removing         auto block_id = GetBlockId(std::to_string(block_count++));
uncomitted_blocks_ids.push_back(block_id); from lambda solved problem. Thanks!
